# Typescript: callback where event can be click or keydown throws Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a setup where click and keydown events call the same callback:

```
const onClick = (e: Event) => {
  callback(e);
};

const onKeydown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  callback(e);
};

const callback = (e) => {
  if ('key' in e && e.key === 'Enter') console.log('yeet');
}
```

I'm simplifying of course, but this is the essence of the setup.

`yarn tsc` is barking that `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'Event'`.

What's the right way to handle this situation? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha:

```
const onClick = (e: Event) => {
  callback(e);
};

const onKeydown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  callback(e);
};

const callback = (e: Event | KeyboardEvent) => {
  if ('key' in e && e.key === 'Enter') console.log('yeet');
}
```